# Getting all tag elements in an array with SwiftSoup

Tags: swift, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, swiftsoup

I worked on a project in python using BeautifulSoup for parsing an Html doc and adding ruby and rt tags to each string. Recently I've been working on a similar project for a personal IOS app. I found SwiftSoup which was similar but ran into a problem parsing a tag which I was able to do beautifully using BeautifulSoup. In Beautiful soup I am able to get a tag like the one below

```
<p id="p6" data-pid="6" data-rel-pid="[41]" class="p6">
  <span class="parNum" data-pnum="1"></span>
     This is a（<span id="citationsource2"></span><a epub:type="noteref" href="#citation2">link</a>）to some website。
</p>
```

using [.content](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) from BS4 I am able to get the tags into an array like this

```
['\n', <span class="parNum" data-pnum="1"></span>, '\n         This is a（', <span id="citationsource2"></span>, <a epub:type="noteref" href="#citation2">link</a>, '）to some website。\n    ']
```

After i go through the array and check if the children tags have text or if the element in the array is a text element and i just append the ruby tags. The result is this

```
 <p id="p6" data-pid="6" data-rel-pid="[41]" class="p6">
  <span class="parNum" data-pnum="1"></span>
     <ruby>This<rt>1</rt></ruby><ruby>is<rt>2</rt></ruby> <ruby>a<rt>3</rt></ruby>（<span id="citationsource2"></span><a epub:type="noteref" href="#citation2"><ruby>link<rt>4</rt></ruby></a>）<ruby>to<rt>5</rt></ruby> <ruby>some<rt>6</rt></ruby> <ruby>website<rt>7</rt></ruby>。
</p>
```

With SwiftSoup I parse the Document doing this since it doesn't have a similar method like the BS4 `.content`

```
let soup:Document = try! SwiftSoup.parse(html)
let elements:Elements = try! soup.select("p")
for j in try! elements.html(){
  
    print(try! j)
   //Doesn't work prints out every single character not every element
}
```

The problem is that it treats the whole content of the `p` tag as an element it doesnt separate the elements in the p tag like BS4 does. I looked at the documentation but I don't see anything about separating the elements from the tag into an array.

This is what I want to achieve with Swiftsoup

```
['\n', <span class="parNum" data-pnum="1"></span>, '\n         This is a（', <span id="citationsource2"></span>, <a epub:type="noteref" href="#citation2">link</a>, '）to some website。\n    ']
```

But end up getting everything as one element in the array instead of seperated elements.

```
[<span class="parNum" data-pnum="1"></span>This is a（<span id="citationsource2"> 
  </span> <a epub:type="noteref" href="#citation2">link</a>）to some website.]
```

Is there any way of achieving this using swiftsoup or another swift html parser that could achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the SwiftSoup files I was able to find the answer to my question. SwiftSoup has a method called `getChildNodes` which allows you to get all the content of the specified tag. It returns an array of the content of the tag. Hope this helps anyone who has also faced a similar problem.

```
let soup:Document = try! SwiftSoup.parseBodyFragment(html)
let p : Elements = try! soup.select("p")
for j in p{
    print(try! j.getChildNodes())

}}
```